# Make the file author property readonly - MS-Word 2007

Tags: properties, microsoft-office, read-only, microsoft-office-2007

I just want to know is there a way of locking a MS-Word files author, while keeping the document editable in MS-Word 2007

currently

- you create a document
- save the document
- right click on the document and go to properties
- go to summary tab

it shows the 'author' of the file and it can be editable.

what I want to do is, lock the author property where nobody can change its value. But I want to allow others to Edit my document content.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the author couldn't be changed after it has been set once? Aren't people that edit your document authors too?

Comment: Hi MOnsDaR, Yes agreed, but the problem is one of my friend has a problem, when he creates a document and send it to his supervisor , he sends it to the management as if the supervisor did it. (without changing a single word) just to show off :D - thanks - sameera

Comment: Duplicate. Sorry the answer is no, you can't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193370/read-only-custom-properties

Comment: is there anyway that a macro can help this. I mean setting the author when editing the properties or something - cheers sameera